# document.write() not working in userscript with Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, greasemonkey, userscripts

I have some userscripts that use

```
var tab = window.open('', '_blank');
tab.document.write(myCustomHtml);
tab.document.close();
```

to show an output to the user (myCustomHtml being some valid HTML I defined previously in the code). It sopped working in Firefox since version 27, now I only get an empty document. No console errors whatsoever.

The newly opened document has only this content when inspected with Firefox' console

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

while the source code is empty.

The code works in Chrome.

Do I need to make any modification for newer Firefox versions (27+) and an updated Greasemonkey (1.15)? I haven't found any recent bug reported to Firefox about this issue.

Here's a test script

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name           document.write() test
// @namespace      stackoverflow.com
// @description    tests document.write()
// @include        https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22651334/*
// @include        http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22651334/*
// @version        0.0.1
// ==/UserScript==

var tab = window.open('', '_blank');
tab.document.write('<html><head></head><body><ul><li>a</li><li>b</li><li>c</li></ul></body></html>');
tab.document.close();
```

Comment: `document.write()` can have all sorts of unwanted effects during the rendering process. Better to add your elements directly to the DOM.

Comment: I know it is a hated function and I'm aware of the risks, but it spares me a lot of lines. I'd prefer to keep it, considering that I'm starting with an empty document, using 'offline' data and a very simple layout.

Comment: I have tested your script in firefox 28 with a simple html markup `"<html><head></head><body> <ul><li>a</li><li>b</li><li>c</li></ul> </body></html>"` and works for me, maybe it is something related to the html you're trying to use.... wait what about the config in your greasemonkey?: I've tested it in a pure html web page.

Comment: Sorry now tested within greasemonkey...same issue.

Comment: Thanks anyway. I added an test script to the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if Greasemonkey or Firefox has buggered this, but `window.open` to a blank page, from a Greasemonkey script, now triggers a [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) violation.
Meanwhile, Page scope, the console scope, and Firebug's console all work fine.

Greasemonkey scope gives:

> SecurityError: The operation is insecure

whether `@grant none` is used or not.

This, plus the general uselessness of [GM_openInTab()](http://wiki.greasespot.net/GM_openInTab), lead me to suspect it is a Greasemonkey bug.  I don't have time to look into it right now, but [file a bug report](https://github.com/greasemonkey/greasemonkey/issues), if you wish.

To get this to work on the latest release of Firefox (28.0) and Greasemonkey (1.15), here's what I had to do:

1. Tell my popup blockers to (temporarily) allow popups from stackoverflow.com.
2. Inject the popup code into the page scope.
3. Use an explicit `about:blank` for the URL.
4. Wait for the new window to load.

Here's a complete script that works on the latest FF+GM *releases*:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        document.write () test
// @description tests document.write ()
// @include     http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22651334/*
// ==/UserScript==

function fireNewTab () {
    var newTab = window.open ('about:blank', '_blank');
    newTab.addEventListener (
        "load",
        function () {
            //--- Now process the popup/tab, as desired.
            var destDoc = newTab.document;
            destDoc.open ();
            destDoc.write ('<html><head></head><body><ul><li>a</li><li>b</li><li>c</li></ul></body></html>');
            destDoc.close ();
        },
        false
    );
}

addJS_Node (null, null, fireNewTab);

function addJS_Node (text, s_URL, funcToRun, runOnLoad) {
    var D                                   = document;
    var scriptNode                          = D.createElement ('script');
    if (runOnLoad) {
        scriptNode.addEventListener ("load", runOnLoad, false);
    }
    scriptNode.type                         = "text/javascript";
    if (text)       scriptNode.textContent  = text;
    if (s_URL)      scriptNode.src          = s_URL;
    if (funcToRun)  scriptNode.textContent  = '(' + funcToRun.toString() + ')()';

    var targ = D.getElementsByTagName ('head')[0] || D.body || D.documentElement;
    targ.appendChild (scriptNode);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, specially for the fully functional snippet replacement. I think this is a conclusive answer for "Do I need to make any modification for newer Firefox versions?". I'll write a ticket for Greasemonkey's guys.

Answer (score -1):

Try using `tab.document.body.innerHTML` instead of `tab.document.write()` and `tab.document.close()`, that is,

```
var tab = window.open('', '_blank');
tab.document.body.innerHTML = '<ul><li>a</li><li>b</li><li>c</li></ul>';
```

(I'm using Firefox v24.4.0 with Greasemonkey v1.15 and that works for me.)

I have no idea regarding the root cause of this issue but when I enclosed `document.write()` in a try-catch block I got the following error message from `alert()`.

`The operation is insecure.`

Possibly related: [Bug 663406 - document.write does not work in devtools scratchpad and console](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=825039)

Comment: That bug is not (too) related, and it was resolved about 3 versions ago, anyway.